# bcrypt npm install error - Error: Cannot find module node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bcrypt

I'm on Windows 10 (version 10.0.17763 build 17763). I'm trying to install Bcrypt with Nodejs Express server using NPM. I've updated the latest Nodejs version (v12.16.3). Whether I install the latest version of Bcrypt or an earlier version, I'm always getting the same error:

[image]

I'm not sure why it's looking for `node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp` in the directoy `C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\web-dev-udemy-course\`. There's no such directory there!! This is just a folder to store my course files.

Also I'm not sure why this is happening:

```
-Security\store-confidential-data-web-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

I've looked in other forums for such error, but no solution helped me. Some are old forums asking to install deprecated modules.

Comment: maybe deleting the node modules and reinstalling them will help. sometime does.

Comment: Ok, I tried deleting `node_modules`, then I installed bcrypt `npm install bcrypt`. That sequence did not work (same error). Then tried a different sequence: delete `node_modules`, then `npm install`, then `npm install bcrypt`. Still get the same error :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after two days of pulling my hair out, trying solutions out and not getting anywhere, I finally found a reddit post with someone having exactly the same issue as me: https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/gahkjl/npm_drives_me_crazy_for_months_looks_for_bin/

It's because I used the `&` character in my folder name. I guess for some reason it throws npm off. Removing this character from my folder name resolved it.

Comment: But how could I change the Users folder name ?

Comment: I just renamed the folder that had the `&` which solved it for me. Just rename the folder from File Explorer.

Comment: You couldn't simply do that for user folder name.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp

That is an NPM package, I would say install node-pre-gyp and then try to install bcrypt

node-gyp is a dependency of bcrypt

I just ran 'npm install bcrypt --save' and it worked

or install this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

Comment: I did `npm i node-pre-gyp`. Which showed that it installed, with output: `+ node-pre-gyp@0.14.0` `added 51 packages from 21 contributors and audited 323 packages in 3.823s`  `found 0 vulnerabilities`. Then I tried installing bcrypt using your suggestion: `npm install
bcrypt --save`, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Note dependencies from package.json,
Install packages individually.

In my case, I tried adding sqlite

```
   "dependencies": {
      "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
   }
```

and ran `npm install`, which did not work.

But then, removed it ,

```
"dependencies": {}
```

and ran

```
npm cache clean
npm install  -g node-gyp
npm install --save sqlite3
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to see the versions of `node-pre-gyp` that are available in the npm registry:

```
npm show node-pre-gyp versions
```

This will display a list of available versions

you can choose a version that suits your requirements

```
npm install node-pre-gyp@0.17.0
```

change  `0.17.0` to the version that suits your requirements

I had this error for two days to fix I hope I helped you.